# How to paste data in a custom format from system clipboard to Flash applet?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, clipboard, copy-paste

I have an in-browser application and a piece of legacy software, which uses a custom data format to interact with system clipboard. I would like to implement copy and paste between the two.

ActionScript claims to support application-defined clipboard data formats, but that seems to only work within one application or between two Flash applications.

**Is it at all possible to paste data from system clipboard, if the format is NOT one of the {TEXT_FORMAT, HTML_FORMAT, RICH_TEXT_FORMAT, BITMAP_FORMAT, FILE_LIST_FORMAT, URL_FORMAT}?**

Comment: I've never done this, but the [getData()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/Clipboard.html#getData()) method of Clipboard supports custom formats. If you are pasting data from your legacy app to Flash, this might work... but it's not clear to me how you make the legacy app specify this custom format. Do you have any code you can share?

Comment: @SunilD. I don't think getData() supports that. The paste handler isn't even invoked, if the data in the clipboard is not in the right format. The paste item in the menu is disabled, too.